# There is no result type defined for type 'jasper' mapped with name 'success'

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports with Struts 2.
In my `struts.xml` file I have included

```
 <package name="billingpkg"  extends="struts-default, json-default,jasperreports-default">
    <action name="myJasperTest" class="iland.bill.SubmitBillAction" method="fetchAll">
            <result name="success" type="jasper">
                <param name="location">/pages/billing/Report1.jasper</param>
                <param name="dataSource">list</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
            </result>
    </action>
  </package>
```

This is showing following error while deploying

```
1) Error building results for action myJasperTest in namespace
2) There is no result type defined for type 'jasper' mapped with name 'success'
```

I have included `jasperreport-5.5.0.jar` in my class lib

How to resolve above error
I am getting following error stack

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: Error building results for action myJasperTest in namespace  - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:389)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'jasper' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'jasper'? - result - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:509:50
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:653)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Dec 2, 2013 3:08:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: Error building results for action myJasperTest in namespace  - action - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:508:91
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:389)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'jasper' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'jasper'? - result - file:/E:/Project/cxn/cnx/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:509:50
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:653)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:387)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @AleksandrM added stacktrace

Comment: Have you included `struts2-jasperreports-plugin` jar?

Comment: Included  jasperreport-5.5.0.jar. As given in http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html

Comment: You need to include plugin jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to donwload and include in your project `JasperReports` AND [`struts2-jasperreports-plugin`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-jasperreports-plugin).

From your comments it does seem that you installed only JasperReports, but not the plugin.

Also be sure to pick up the same version of your Struts2 jar.

Comment: Yes you are correct It was giving error due to not included the ` struts2-jasperreports-plugin`. I have included the correct version of plug in now this problem has solved